# MP3 Sample Size?

Tags: audio

I am trying to write a c# program that performs **steganography** with audio files like .wav and .mp3. The .wav file sample size was easy to calculate but I am having difficulties trying to figure out how to calculate the **sample size of an MP3 file**.

Can someone provide a formula to calculate the sample size of an MP3 file a.k.a. "**bit per sample** " , "**bit depth**"?

Comment: Please don't making the entire question bold.

Comment: Are you talking about the uncompressed audio bit depth?  Or are you talking about the compressed bit rate?  Be more specific.

Comment: hi @Brad i dont know actually cus i dont have a wide knowledge about mp3 files but all i want is the sample size whether its compressed or not
and sorry for the late response

Comment: @muhammadalbasrawe, How do you expect a useful answer if you don't know what the question is yet!?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the actual bit depth of the PCM audio that the MP3 will decode to.  Unfortunately, this depends on the material recorded.

MP3 does not use a hard-set bit depth.  It uses floating point samples internally.  It is up to the decoder to select an output bit depth.  For most program material, this will be 16-bit.

Comment: hi @Brad thanks for the info.
but how about this formula

Bit rate = (sampling rate) × (bit depth) × (number of channels)

E.g., for a recording with a 44.1 kHz sampling rate, a 16 bit depth, and 2 channels (stereo):

44100 samples per second per channel × 16 bits per sample × 2 channels = 1411200 bits per second = 1411.2 kbit/s 

-----------------------------------------------------
then from the formula above
if i have all the variables
except the bit depth 
i would consider it as x and calculate it
is that right

Comment: @muhammadalbasrawe, You are talking about uncompressed audio, which has nothing to do with MPEG.